# How does answer of this integral equal to kronecker delta?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, kronecker-delta

I can't figure out how does the result of this integral equal to $\delta_{mn}$ ?!
$$\frac{1}{T_0}\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+T_0}e^{-\frac{j2\pi(n-m)}{T_0}}\,dt$$
**PS**: Is there any easy or intuitive approach to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just integrate directly. If $n=m$, the exponent is zero
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{T_0}\int_\alpha^{\alpha+T_0}\,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{t}{T_0}\,\bigg|^{\alpha+T_0}_\alpha = 1.
\end{equation}
Otherwise,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{T_0}\int_\alpha^{\alpha+T_0}e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}t}\,\mathrm{d}t = -\frac{e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}t}}{2\pi i(n-m)}\,\bigg|^{\alpha+T_0}_\alpha = \frac{e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}\alpha}-e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}(\alpha+T_0)}}{2\pi i(n-m)} = \frac{e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}\alpha} - e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}\alpha}e^{-2\pi i(n-m)}}{2\pi i(n-m)} = \frac{e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}\alpha}-e^{-\frac{2\pi i(n-m)}{T_0}\alpha}}{2\pi i(n-m)} = 0.
\end{equation}